# Spring Boot @ConfigurationProperties - Change property key

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have an interesting use case where the field name that is used in a class annotated with `@ConfigurationProperties` should be different from the corresponding key used in the (yaml) configuration file:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("foo")
class ConfProps {

    private List<SomePojo> bar = new ArrayList<>();

    // getter, setter

}
```

This will "look out for" `foo.bar`. Is it possible to map the field `bar` to a different property key?

I read the [the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) and some related articles, but nothing ...

To me it seems that either it's because it is absolutely trivial or this is some kind of non-goal.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well you can't have different config key and mapping property name. That's how spring resolves the auto-mapping.

However, if having a different property field is so essential for you have can have a hack.

Put a dummy setter like this.

Property key:
`foo.bar`

Config class:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("foo")
class ConfProps {

    private List<SomePojo> differentlyNamedList = new ArrayList<>();

    // getter, setter

    public void setBar(List<SomePojo> bar){
       this.differentlyNamedList = bar;
    }
}
```

Comment: It works. Normally I try to go without undocumented hacks but since this is just is a very small one I guess it's okay. Thank you for your quick help!

Comment: I don't think this works for immutable configurations / constructor binding.

Answer (score 1):

Chaning the mapping is impossible, at least for now. You have to use a custom setter (as @Amit stated), but this seems to be kind of workaround.

I have filled an [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/37105) about it in spring-boot repository. It is still pending however.