# How define properties names using @ConfigurationProperties in Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have class:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "user")
public class BarcodeConfig {
    private String customName;
    private Details customDetails;
```

And property file with:

```
user.name=sampleName
user.details.address=sampleAddress
user.details.something=sampleSomething
```

How map "user.name" to field "customName" and "user.details.*" to "customeDetails" without changing field names?

Comment: Try the solution mentioned here? https://stackoverflow.com/a/52961096/3833858

Answer (score 0):

you can use `@AliasFor("name")`

Comment: Can you write code example? Can't use @AliasFor for field, tried with getter, but no effect.

Answer (score -2):

You have to provide the property path from your configuration file using the @Value annotation.

For example, if you want to map the user.name to customName:

```
...
@Value(${user.name})
private String customName;
...
```

Spring will automatically fetch the user.name property value and assigns it to the customName variable attribute.

Comment: It'd work for primitive types and Spring beans only (Details isn't bean)